# Calculate with separate results

Tags: javascript, php

I just cant figure it out :(

Tried a lot of combinations, just ending up in only errors.

What I'm trying to do is this:
- 2 rows of checkboxes.
Row 1 contains a checkbox with value:

```
<input onclick="clickCh(this)" type="checkbox" name="row1" value="1">
```

Row 2 contains a checkbox with value:

```
<input onclick="clickCh(this)" type="checkbox" name="row2" value="2">
```

Resulting in:

```
<input id="row1" type="text" name="total"> Row one results.
<input id="row2" type="text" name="total"> Row two results.
<input id="total" type="text" name="total"> Row one and two results combined.
```

The script i use:

```
var total = document.getElementById("total")
function clickCh(caller){
if(caller.checked){
add(caller)
} else {
subtract(caller)
}
}
function add(caller){   total.value = total.value*1 + caller.value*1}
function subtract(caller){  total.value = total.value*1 - caller.value*1}
```

The script itself is not mine, i just found it on this website

Comment: Semi colon after getelementbyid?

Comment: I'm not seeing a question in there. The lack of a question mark anywhere in the text backs up my theory...

Comment: -2 rows of checkboxes?

Comment: The script appears to come from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190960/sum-radio-button-values-and-checkboxes-values-in-one-calculation-javascript-an

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle to play with... it does seem to be producing errors: http://jsfiddle.net/Fwd8J/

Comment: To put totals in all three boxes, you'll have to use three copies of the code you're using, and you'll have to modify them to not conflict with each other.  That's a little too much "write your code for you" for me right now...

Comment: Many thanks Brilliand!! Im not asking for someone to write stuff for me, but thats the answer wich i was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as posted only runs without errors when run globally (not within the onload event or any other function) - a small change can fix that:

```
var total = document.getElementById("total")
clickCh = function(caller){
if(caller.checked){
add(caller)
} else {
subtract(caller)
}
}
function add(caller){   total.value = total.value*1 + caller.value*1}
function subtract(caller){  total.value = total.value*1 - caller.value*1}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fwd8J/1/

(The change is on line 2 - assigning the function to a variable assures that it goes into the global scope.)

A better way to do this would be to assign the `clickCh` function to the `onclick` event of each checkbox within the script, so as to not contaminate the global scope.